# Variation name in $product->get_name()

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

On product page there are custom variations displayed so user can select different variations.
On cart page after getting product name `$product->get_name()`, name has variation name|description added at the end.

I need first remove this addon and then echo it in another place(near div).
How do i do that on cart page?

Comment: I found that there is an array [attributes] in [data:protected] {top level of product object} with key that written in russian symbols %d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%bc

Comment: this array-key has a needed value for me, how do i print it ?

Comment: getting it via -get_attributes() or -get_attirbute( those symbols ), sadly doesnt help. in 1st case returned array just dont have custom variation terms , in second just null

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense at the moment, can you please re-explain your question with better examples (code) and a screenshot of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have been able to get solution by investigating $_product array and finding proper attributes, then accessing them via get_attribute function. And to display only name i used _get_title()

Comment: @Adam sorry for poor explanation. If u may be need more clarification just in case. Here it is. I created variations on product to add different prices with different product packages. If user pick a single variation on a product page and add it to cart, then on cart page product item appears as that variation with the name {ProductName}+{VariationName}, i needed to cut that {VariationName} suffix which i did with get_title() function for $product. Also i need to echo that {VariationName} in different place and i solved it via get_attribute